# Minute.steps parameter unused argument error for timeTinput

Tags: r, shiny

I have trying to put a step of 15 minutes on my timeInput for a shiny app but the argument minute.steps is not recognised. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTime)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("shinyTime Example App"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      timeInput(inputId = "time_input", label = "Enter time", value = strptime("12:34:56", "%T"), minute.steps = 15)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("time_output")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$time_output <- renderText(strftime(input$time_input, "%T"))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Error in timeInput(inputId = "time_input", label = "Enter time", value = strptime("12:34:56",  : 
  unused argument (minute.steps = 15)
```

I check my package installation (shinyTime), everything looks ok.

Comment: Your app woks fine for me.

Comment: What are your versions of R, shiny & shinyTime? It works ok for R 3.5.0, shinyTime_1.0.0, shiny_1.2.0. Use `sessionInfo()` to find out

Comment: Interesting fact. I was using shiny_1.1.0. After upgrading it to 1.3.2, it works. Thanks.